# Set theme programatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to set my custom theme programatically for default scope. So far, I have just found out that setting it only in `core_config_data` is not enough. Has anyone tried to do it that way?

Comment: In your case, we need to reindex.

Comment: you mean that it is enough, but I should reindex? I think your answer may be more appriopriate and I will try it tommorow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign a theme in Magento 2 using a setup script?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140026/how-to-assign-a-theme-in-magento-2-using-a-setup-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\StoresSetup\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Theme\Model\ThemeFactory;
use Magento\Theme\Model\Config;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Theme\Model\Data\Design\Config as DesignConfig;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    const THEME_NAME = 'Vendor/theme';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Theme\Model\Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @var IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var ReinitableConfigInterface
     */
    protected $reinitableConfig;

    /**
     * @var StoresFactory
     */
    protected $storesFactory;

    /**
     * @var ThemeFactory
     */
    protected $themeFactory;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     *
     * @param StoresFactory $storesFactory
     * @param Config $config
     * @param ThemeFactory $themeFactory
     * @param ReinitableConfigInterface $reinitableConfig
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoresFactory $storesFactory,
        Config $config,
        ThemeFactory $themeFactory,
        ReinitableConfigInterface $reinitableConfig,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
    ) {
        $this->storesFactory = $storesFactory;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->themeFactory = $themeFactory;
        $this->reinitableConfig = $reinitableConfig;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->assignTheme();
        $this->reinitableConfig->reinit();
        $this->indexerRegistry->get(DesignConfig::DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_INDEXER_ID)->reindexAll();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Assign Theme
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function assignTheme()
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Theme\Model\Theme $theme
         */
        $theme = $this->themeFactory->create()->load(self::THEME_NAME, 'code');
        if ($theme->getId()) {
            $this->config->assignToStore(
                $theme,
                [Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID],
                ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a new module in the example i add a module Vendor/Theme with a an Setup/InstallData.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Theme\Setup;

    use Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\Store as StoreModel;
    use Magento\Theme\Model\Data\Design\Config as DesignConfig;
    use Magento\Theme\Model\ThemeFactory;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var Config
         */
        private $scopeConfig;
        /**
         * @var IndexerRegistry
         */
        private $indexerRegistry;
        /**
         * @var ReinitableConfigInterface
         */
        private $reinitableConfig;
        /**
         * @var ThemeFactory
         */
        private $themeFactory;

        public function __construct(
            Config $scopeConfig,
            IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
            ReinitableConfigInterface $reinitableConfig,
            ThemeFactory $themeFactory
        ) {
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
            $this->reinitableConfig = $reinitableConfig;
            $this->themeFactory = $themeFactory;
        }

        /**
         * Installs data for a module
         *
         * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
         * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();

            // Retrieves Vendor Theme
            $vendorTheme = $this->themeFactory->create()->load('Vendor/default', 'theme_path');
            // Set Vendor Theme as default on all Websites
            $this->scopeConfig->saveConfig(
                DesignInterface::XML_PATH_THEME_ID,
                $vendorTheme->getId(),
                ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT,
                StoreModel::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            );
            // Reindex Flat Theme table
            $this->reinitableConfig->reinit();
            $this->indexerRegistry
                ->get(DesignConfig::DESIGN_CONFIG_GRID_INDEXER_ID)
                ->reindexAll();

            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```